# Can you boot up raspberry pi4 after shutting down with keyboard

Tags: raspberry-pi

I searched for a solution to reboot raspberry pi 4 after shutting down but only I can find that you wire a switch to reboot it. Is there a program or a script to remotly start up raspberry pi by pressing some button on the keyboard. Because I am using mine a smart tv replacement and want to know is it possible to reboot remotly without getting out of bed? :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a good solution, which I tested is to directly connect the raspberry pi to the tv via usb, so when you turn on the television as the command the rasp also turns on :)